# I have this `div` on my home page and want it to move with me when I scroll, I am using react for the website btw

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this `div` on my home page and want it to move with me when I scroll:
I tried using position:sticky; and position: fixed and adding top: 600px; but its not moving to the top its stuck at the bottom

```css
.linkss {
  color: #8892b0;
  font-family: 'NTR', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 680px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: fixed;
}

.linkss h3 {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #c9c1f5;
}

.linkss a {
  border: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #c9c1f5;
  height: 30px;
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div className="linkss">
  <h3>/ Links</h3>
  <a href="https://www.etsy.com/ca/shop/VanillaUnlimited">/ Etsy Shop </a>
  <a href="https://www.etsy.com/ca/shop/VanillaUnlimited">/ LinkedIn </a>
  <a href="https://www.etsy.com/ca/shop/VanillaUnlimited">/ Instagram </a>
</div>
```

Comment: there's a w3schools [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) for that.

Comment: @Lars it won't let me move it to the top of the page its stuck at the bottom

Comment: For attached code it will always be stuck at 680px from top of view as you set top: 680px. Please clarify what are you trying to achive.

Comment: @rawan arafat I get it from the code that you want the links to always be on the top when the user scrolls, right?. so you just need to add position: sticky; and top:0px; or something smaller like 20px or 30px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's stuck to the bottom because you have given `top:680px;`  decrease it to something smaller like `20px`. And set the position property to `position:sticky;`

Comment: I changed it and its still stuck at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You need to use addEventListener in componentDidMount as below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', this.doSomething)
}

doSomething = () => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
     // add a new class (with top: 0) to element or change style of element by top = 0
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: actually, he doesn't want it to be at the bottom. he wants it to move to the top when the user scrolls.